# can we use two selectors under one column in react data-table component?

Tags: react-data-table-component

I am using react data-table component and I want to display 2 fields under one header. But the issue is that I don't know the correct method to use react-data-table-component and the instruction of react-data-table-component do not include such example.

So I wanted to know whether we can use two selectors under one column.

Below is my code :

```
{
  name:<div style={{ cursor: 'context-menu' , marginRight:'80px'}}>Implementation</div>,
  selector: 'ImplementationStatus',
  selector: 'DoneDate',

  ignoreRowClick: true,
  cell: row => (
  <div>
  <div style={{display: 'inline-block',marginRight:'10px',color:row.ImplementationStatus == 0 ? "red" : (row.ImplementationStatus == 1 ? "#fe9810" : (row.ImplementationStatus == 2 ? "green" : "black"))}}>{row.ImplementationStatus == 0 ? <div style={{marginRight:'5px'}}>NOT STARTED</div> : (row.ImplementationStatus == 1 ? <div style={{marginRight:'20px'}}>UNDERWAY</div> : (row.ImplementationStatus == 2 ? "IMPLEMENTED" : ""))}</div>
  
    <div className="align-middle text-center" style={{display: 'inline-block',paddingLeft:'0px'}}>
      <Input style={{ width: '167px',fontSize:'15px', height: '30px',backgroundColor:this.state.isManager === true || this.state.isAdmin===true ?'#FFFFFF':'#DCDCDC'}}
        type="date"
        readOnly={this.state.isManager === true || this.state.isAdmin === true ? false : true}
        placeholder="Enter Done Date"
        value={row.DoneDateVendorDisplay == null ? "2020-01-01" : row.DoneDateVendorDisplay}
        min="2020-01-01"
        max={currentDate}
      /></div>
      </div>
  ),
  center: true,
  width: 'auto',
},
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector property for columns API, can be a string or function. In the example below I combine "firstName" and "lastName" to produce a "name" column

```
<DataTable
  columns={[
    {
      name: 'Name',
      selector: row => `${ row.firstName } ${ row.lastName }`
    },
    {
      name: 'Business Number',
      selector: 'businessNumber'
    },
    {
      name: 'Type',
      selector: 'type'
    }
  ]}
/>
```